# How to get user's information from Facebook in the server side (PHP) in an Android application

Tags: php, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an Android application where the user authenticates his **Facebook** Login, then I need to get this user's information in the server side (**PHP**) 
What I did is that I obtained the access token from the Android after Login then sent it to the server side in order to get the user information directly through the pre-obtained access token, but apparently this is not the way it should work, because in **PHP** I initiate a new Facebook instance

`$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $appid,
        'secret' => $app_secret
        ));`
so does any body have a solution to how to pass the access token or the user ID to Facebook and open a session directly instead of logging-in again in the server side in order to open a session?
Thanks A lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

`$facebook->setAccessToken("....");`

The token is the one that you get on Android. You should be able to make calls to the api now, with the new token you've assigned the object with.

`var_dump($facebook->api('/me'));`

Comment: ok what happened is that the Application threw this exception 
`couldn't connect to host  thrown in base_facebook.php on line 994`
you have any idea about this exception?